# How can i get User.Identity values without using the Authorize attribute?

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm developing an api which is using JwtBearer for authentication.When I'm try to using User.Identity like this;

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
       if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
          return ...
       }
       else
       {
          return ..
       }
    }
```

User not contain token/user data and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always return false. But if i add

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

This get User data but i want unauthenticated user can access too.

How could I do this without an Authorize filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, as well, if you want to allow unauthenticated users. You must have `[Authorize]` attribute for the user principal to be established.

Comment: I add `[Authorize]`on controller , `[AllowAnonymous]` on action and its solve my problem. Thanks for help.